# Node.js stops on options

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, server

I send an XMLHttpRequest of type POST and when I do it the server shutdown and says

```
usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96
        this._callback.apply(this, arguments);
                       ^

TypeError: this._callback.apply is not a function
    at Query.Sequence.end (/usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:399:18
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:13
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

My server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var app = express();


app.use(cors());
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));



var db_con = mysql.createConnection({
   host : 'localhost',
   user : 'root',
   password : '****',
   database : 'quizz'
});

 app.post('/questions', function (request, response){
  var query = db_con.query("SELECT DISTINCT question_id, description FROM QUESTION WHERE country=?", [request.body.country]," ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5", function(err,result ) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);

    response.json({"questions": result});
    });
 });

 var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Listening at http://%s:%s', server.address().address,    server.address().port);
  });
```

client code:

```
function get_questions(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST' , 'http://localhost:8080/questions', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');

    xhr.onload = function(){

        if (!response.error) {
          var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          var Score = response;
          var output = Score;

          console.log(Score);
        }

     };
     xhr.send(JSON.stringify( {"country": "Saudi Arabia"} ) );
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look like that:

```
var query = db_con.query("SELECT DISTINCT question_id, description FROM QUESTION WHERE country=? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5", [request.body.country], function(err,result) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);

  response.json({"questions": result});
});
```

The first argument should be the query string, the second should be parameters, and the third should be callback.

The next time you have similar problem, [RTM](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#performing-queries) first.